# Почему результат не печатается?

Tags: python, range

Почему результат не печатается?

```
l = [123,42,54,13,545,63]

for x in range(0,len(l),-1):
    print(l[x])
```

Comment: наверное потому что от 0  до неотрицательного числа нельзя дойти с отрицательным шагом.
Условие цикла никогда не выполнятся если вам так понятнее

Comment: А какой должен быть результат? Если хотите распечатать список задом наперёд, то `range` должен быть такой: `range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1)`. Хотя для этой задачи часто делают так: `print(*l[::-1], sep='\n')`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 , в первом варианте я немного не понял кое-что - разве функция range() имеет 4 аргумента? что значит последний аргумент?

Comment: @MangoJuice 3 аргумента: `range(start, stop, step)`. Вы, наверное, спутали минус с запятой, присмотритесь внимательнее, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

потому что вы передали в `range` неправильный параметры. Надо писать так:

```
range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1):
```

либо

```
range(0, len(l))[::-1]):
```

это также можно сделать без цикла:

```
print(*l[::-1], sep = "\n")
```

либо

```
print("\n".join(map(str, l[::-1])))
```

Answer (score 2):

наверное потому что от 0 до неотрицательного числа нельзя дойти с отрицательным шагом. Условие цикла никогда не выполнятся если вам так понятнее
Наверное вы имели ввиду это:

```
l = [123,42,54,13,545,63]

for elem in l[::-1]:
    print(elem)
    


63
545
13
54
42
123
```

Так больше похоже на Python

Comment: Ещё можно использовать reversed(l) вместо l[::-1]

Comment: Да, пожалуй так будет  лучше.
Хотя нет.  l.reverse()  отсортирует исходный список. 
А автору это похоже не надо )

Comment: с чего вы взяли что `l.reverse` отсортирует список?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets reversed() это отдельная функция, я не говорил про метод у списка l.reverse(), вот подробнее про reversed(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed